# Build node.js app using yarn but getting error Command "build" not found

Tags: node.js

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "moneymall",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A money mall server app.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Anbu Selvan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "e": "0.0.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "yarn": "^1.15.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8"
  }
}
```

Run `yarn build` and get this error.

> yarn run v1.15.2 error Command "build" not found. info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
>   command

Answer (score 5):

You don't seem to have a `script.build` key defined in your `package.json` file. Sample entry for building with `webpack` library would be:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you execute `yarn run` it will show the list of commands which can be run.

Ideally `yarn run dev` will do the trick of compiling the build

Answer (score 1):

Please re-read the yarn documentation. You don't seem to have a script key declaring what you build script is, and thus Yarn does not know what to load.